# Problem installing inkscape

Tags: 16.04, apt, updates, inkscape

I have been trying to install inkscape, but it keep generating these errors below. Can someone please help me resolve this?

Error:

```
 % sudo apt install inkscape                                          [10:33AM]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libgtkspell0 libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 libwmf-bin perlmagick python-uniconvertor
Suggested packages:
  dia | dia-gnome libgnomevfs2-extra libxml-xql-perl pstoedit imagemagick-doc
  python-uniconvertor-dbg
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  inkscape libgtkspell0 libimage-magick-perl libimage-magick-q16-perl
  libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 libwmf-bin perlmagick python-uniconvertor
0 upgraded, 8 newly installed, 0 to remove and 12 not upgraded.
Need to get 320 kB/17.3 MB of archives.
After this operation, 132 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 amd64 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libimage-magick-q16-perl amd64 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Ign:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main i386 libimage-magick-perl all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Ign:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe i386 perlmagick all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libimage-magick-perl all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Err:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 amd64 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 perlmagick all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 libimage-magick-q16-perl amd64 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libimage-magick-perl all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Ign:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 perlmagick all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
Err:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main i386 libimage-magick-perl all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Err:4 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe i386 perlmagick all 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libmagick++-6.q16-5v5_6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libimage-magick-q16-perl_6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/i/imagemagick/libimage-magick-perl_6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/i/imagemagick/perlmagick_6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9_all.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]

E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
```

UPDATE:
the `sudo apt-get update` has this errors:

```
 % sudo apt-get update                                                
Err:30 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
Ign:37 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:40 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:50 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/multiverse amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:28 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:74 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Err:58 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
Ign:63 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:48 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Err:59 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
Ign:72 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:74 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:48 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
Ign:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:75 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  404  Not Found
Ign:79 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
Ign:80 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main all Packages
Ign:81 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en_US
Ign:82 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main Translation-en
Ign:83 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:84 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Fetched 329 kB in 11s (28.0 kB/s)                                              
Reading package lists... Done
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com rodeo InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
W: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-updates/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-updates_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.26 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/us.archive.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-backports_main_dep11_Components-amd64.yml.xz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.91.23 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/xenial-security/main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar  Could not open file /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_xenial-security_main_dep11_icons-64x64.tar.gz - open (13: Permission denied) [IP: 91.189.88.161 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu/dists/xenial/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get update` and try again.

Comment: @N0rbert I did that as well

Comment: `404  Not Found` seems a pretty clear indication of the problem. Verify that you have network connectivity. If so, then wait a couple minutes for those mirrors to come back up.

Comment: This answer helps me:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084047/ubuntu-16-04-wont-install-inkscape