# Ubuntu 16.04 won't install inkscape

Tags: 16.04, system-installation, compiling, cmake, inkscape

I have been trying to install inkscape from the source (also tried apt install), but I keep getting the errors below. Would someone please give me the solution? Thanks!

Error messages:

```
@owner-HP-Z840-Workstation ~/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3/build
 % cmake ..                                                           [ 3:40PM]
------------------------------
Building Makefile for Inkscape
------------------------------
Source Dir: /home/owner/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3
Binary Dir: /home/owner/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3/build
-- Creating build files in: /home/owner/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3/build
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- The CXX compiler identification is GNU 5.4.0
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting C compile features
-- Detecting C compile features - done
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
-- Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
-- Detecting CXX compile features
-- Detecting CXX compile features - done
-- Could NOT find GTest (missing: GTEST_LIBRARY GTEST_INCLUDE_DIR GTEST_MAIN_LIBRARY) 
No gmock/gtest found! Perhaps you wish to run 'bash download-gtest.sh' to download it.
-- Found PkgConfig: /usr/bin/pkg-config (found version "0.29.1") 
-- Checking for modules 'pangocairo;pangoft2;fontconfig;gthread-2.0;gsl;gmodule-2.0'
--   Found pangocairo, version 1.38.1
--   Found pangoft2, version 1.38.1
--   Found fontconfig, version 2.11.94
--   Found gthread-2.0, version 2.48.2
--   Found gsl, version 2.1
--   Found gmodule-2.0, version 2.48.2
-- Checking for module 'x11'
--   Found x11, version 1.6.3
-- Checking for module 'gnome-vfs-2.0'
--   No package 'gnome-vfs-2.0' found
-- Found LCMS2: /usr/local/lib/liblcms2.so  
-- Performing Test ICONV_SECOND_ARGUMENT_IS_CONST
-- Performing Test ICONV_SECOND_ARGUMENT_IS_CONST - Failed
-- Found Iconv: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so
-- Found Intl: /usr/include  
-- Found BoehmGC: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgc.so
-- Checking for module 'poppler'
--   No package 'poppler' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpg-0.3'
--   No package 'libwpg-0.3' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpg-0.2'
--   No package 'libwpg-0.2' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-0.9' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-stream-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-stream-0.9' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpg-0.1'
--   No package 'libwpg-0.1' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpg-stream-0.1'
--   No package 'libwpg-stream-0.1' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-0.8'
--   No package 'libwpd-0.8' found
-- Checking for module 'libvisio-0.1'
--   No package 'libvisio-0.1' found
-- Checking for module 'libvisio-0.0'
--   No package 'libvisio-0.0' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-0.9' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-stream-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-stream-0.9' found
-- Checking for module 'libcdr-0.1'
--   No package 'libcdr-0.1' found
-- Checking for module 'libcdr-0.0'
--   No package 'libcdr-0.0' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-0.9' found
-- Checking for module 'libwpd-stream-0.9'
--   No package 'libwpd-stream-0.9' found
-- Found JPEG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libjpeg.so (found version "80") 
-- Found ZLIB: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so (found version "1.2.8") 
-- Found PNG: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpng.so (found version "1.2.54") 
-- Checking for module 'popt'
--   No package 'popt' found
CMake Error at CMakeScripts/Modules/FindPopt.cmake:82 (message):
  Could not find Popt
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeScripts/DefineDependsandFlags.cmake:194 (find_package)
  CMakeLists.txt:112 (include)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
See also "/home/owner/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeOutput.log".
See also "/home/owner/Downloads/inkscape-INKSCAPE_0_92_3/build/CMakeFiles/CMakeError.log".
```

################Additionally apt get install gives the following errors

```
sudo apt update                                                    [ 3:52PM]
Err:1 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:2 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease        
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Err:3 http://us.old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease      
  Could not resolve 'us.old-releases.ubuntu.com'
Ign:4 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:5 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu xenial InRelease          
Ign:8 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease          
Hit:9 http://cran.rstudio.com/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease               
Hit:10 http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com rodeo InRelease                               
Err:11 http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release           
  404  Not Found [IP: 91.189.88.41 80]
Ign:13 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease                          
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/inkscape.dev/stable/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Get:15 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release [6,596 B]            
Hit:16 https://deb.nodesource.com/node_7.x xenial InRelease                    
Hit:17 https://apt.dockerproject.org/repo ubuntu-xenial InRelease         
Ign:18 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kalakris/cmake/ubuntu xenial InRelease    
Hit:6 https://americas.oxfordnanoportal.com/apt trusty-stable InRelease        
Hit:19 http://cran.stat.ucla.edu/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial/ InRelease            
Hit:21 http://ppa.launchpad.net/nilarimogard/webupd8/ubuntu xenial InRelease   
Ign:22 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial InRelease 
Hit:23 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ubuntu-mate-dev/xenial-mate/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:24 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu xenial InRelease       
Hit:25 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-2/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Hit:26 http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/sublime-text-3/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Err:27 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kalakris/cmake/ubuntu xenial Release           
  404  Not Found
Err:28 http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release
  404  Not Found
Reading package lists... Done
E: The repository 'http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
N: Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://rodeo-deb.yhat.com rodeo InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/kalakris/cmake/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/thefanclub/grive-tools/ubuntu xenial Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

installlation error:

```
@owner-HP-Z840-Workstation ~/Downloads/cmake-3.13.0-rc1-Linux-x86_64/bin
 % sudo apt install inkscape                                          [ 3:52PM]
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 inkscape : Depends: libgtkspell0 (>= 2.0.10) but it is not installable
            Depends: libmagick++-6.q16-5v5 (>= 8:6.8.9.9-7ubuntu5.9) but it is not installable
            Recommends: libwmf-bin but it is not installable
            Recommends: perlmagick but it is not installable
            Recommends: python-uniconvertor but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: @pomsky Please see my updated question

Comment: Why do you have `old-releases.ubuntu.com` for 16.04 (Xenial)? It is still supported.

Comment: I have no clue. How do I update it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/866901/what-can-i-do-if-a-repository-ppa-does-not-have-a-release-file) and [Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'xxx' doesn't support architecture 'i386'](https://askubuntu.com/questions/741410/skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-main-binary-i386-packages-as-repository-x)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to fix the issue with the following steps:

`sudo gedit /etc/apt/sources.list`

delete the old release or broken links (basically delete everything on the opened file), then paste the following, save and close the file:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20160420.1)]/ xenial main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted universe multiverse
# deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-proposed main restricted universe multiverse
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
```

Then finally,`sudo apt-get update`. Then you can install: `sudo apt install inkscape`.